# Web.config Rewrite Rules for specific pages to HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, web-config

I have a requirement whereby I need to redirect all page bar a few to https.

I have the following:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/private$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/commercial$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/badcredit$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <!--<rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/home/private" ignoreCase="true" />
      <match url="/home/commercial" ignoreCase="true" />
      <match url="/home/badcredit" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So I would like all traffic to run over https. Apart from the three routes above which should run over http.

If I uncomment in the above code I get a 400 error on the site. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT

Ok, I have reduced to a single case in order to test. So as follows the following is now running;

```xml
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/private$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/commercial$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/home/badcredit$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^/home/private$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

However, navigating to /home/private is still forcing HTTPS?

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple `<match...` nodes under a `<rule>`, remove two and use an `or` regular expression in the `url` attribute. Just an idea to try out.

Comment: thanks for the reply peter. I added a single match, but still get the same error? I'll update the question to show